# C++ makefile script

Tags: c++, makefile

I have several very long compilation lines, and I want to make them a little more automatized and easier to use, by creating a script. I have found that `makefile` should be good for this purpose, however I am struggling with the file format.

My compilation line looks something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG              \
  -I /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/include \
  -L /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/lib     \
  main.cpp                               \
  -o program                             \
  -lsdsl -ldivsufsort -ldivsufsort64 -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override
```

So I have several compiler flags, then `include` and `lib` parts, then linker options, and then ignore warnings flag.

I tried to write a `makefile` like this:

```
# what compiler to use
CC=g++

# options to the compiler
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -03 -DNDEBUG

# include header files
INCLUDE=-I /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/include

# source lib files
LIB=-L /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/lib

# sources
SOURCES=main.cpp

#executable
EXECUTABLE=main
```

But I am not sure how to proceed. Could anyone help me out with the example `makefile` for this compile line, so I understand the concept?

Comment: Proceed writing a rule for `main`? Also what's unclear from make's [reference documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)?

Comment: Shell script != Makefile. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: `target: space delimitied dependencies\n\tcommand to create target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with something simple and straightforward that works:

```
program:
    g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG      \
-I /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/include \
-L /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/lib     \
main.cpp                               \
-o program                             \
-lsdsl -ldivsufsort -ldivsufsort64 -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override
```

Then introduce a variable or two:

```
# what compiler to use
CC=g++

# options to the compiler
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -03 -DNDEBUG

program:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)      \
-I /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/include \
-L /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/lib     \
main.cpp                               \
-o program                             \
-lsdsl -ldivsufsort -ldivsufsort64 -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override
```

Then a few more:

```
# what compiler to use
CC=g++

# options to the compiler
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -03 -DNDEBUG

# include header files
INCLUDE=-I /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/include

# source lib files
LIB=-L /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/lib

program:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIB)  \
main.cpp                               \
-o program                             \
-lsdsl -ldivsufsort -ldivsufsort64 -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override
```

The variable LIB actually refers to a directory, so let's rename it LIBDIR and introduce LIBS:

```
# what compiler to use
CC=g++

# options to the compiler
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -03 -DNDEBUG

# include header files
INCLUDE=-I /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/include

# source lib files
LIBDIR=-L /Users/whizzil/Desktop/proj/lib

LIBS = -lsdsl -ldivsufsort -ldivsufsort64

program:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBDIR) main.cpp \
-o program $(LIBS) -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override
```

Further refinements are possible, once you have that much working.